# Can't get the whole word using xpath

Tags: php, curl, xpath

Im working on a simple curl which I get the specific contents using xpath. my problem is the data is not complete. When I try to get this word 美原油连续 inside the h1 tag, it returns only the first 3 characters.

this is my code.

```
$title = $xpath->query('//h1')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: have you tried '//h1/text()' ?

Comment: @Akash yea..I wonder maybe its generated by javascript..